# Can't delete a user, or even find it in the system

Tags: macos, user-account

I got a user that I can't delete, I have no idea where it's stored.
I see it in the top bar, but not in Settings->Users or in `/Users/`

How do I find the PostgreSQL user and delete it?

I can't create a user named postgresql, since it's used. So there is a user in the system somewhere.

MacOS 14.4, I got two users working normal.

[image: Users in top bar]

[image: Users in settings]

[image: Users on disk]

Comment: Try issuing the command `dscl . -list users`.   Can you find the PostgreSQL user now?

Comment: The output of Allan's comment will allow us to edit my answer to let you delete the user from the command line rather than have you fill in all the pieces or [adapt a similar request to delete an account that exists in the GUI](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/454318/5472) to your similar but different situation.

Comment: You two helped me solve this. Thanks! "sudo dscl . -delete /Users/postgres"

Comment: Additionally to the dscl command macOS also offers an application to deal with this sort of thing (easiest found via Spotlight): `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications/Directory Utility.app`

Answer (score 1):

On macOS not all unix users have a shell or home folder in the Users folder. [Here's another question showing how to create a PostgreSQL user and make a non-standard home folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68976839/475228).

I wonder if you just need to reset the password so you can use that account? Do you need a GUI user with this name, as most of the time a created user is just fine to run SQL type processes you install.

Answer (score 1):

That particular user is the user account that runs the PostgreSQL server database.  Many operational services like mail, printing etc. have a non-login user under which it runs because you don’t want everything running as root nor a standard user with login capabilities.

To get the details on a specific user, issue the command

```
dscl . -read /Users/USERNAME
```

To delete the user as you asked, issue the command

```
sudo dscl . -delete /Users/USERNAME
```

Comment: OP got it working with `sudo dscl . -delete /Users/postgres`